# How to pass the image buffer to Tensorflow JS decodeImage method?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io, tensorflow.js

So I have the following code;
`CLIENT`

```
const imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, 320, 180);
const buffer = imageData.data.buffer;
socket.emit("signal", buffer); //Pass it to the server through websocket
```

`BACKEND`

```
socket.on("signal", (data)=> {
　　const buffer = new Uint8Array(data);
　　const imgData = ts.node.decodeImage(buffer); //error throwns here.
})
```

on the backend, I've tried to decode the buffer, but this error was thrown out.

```
throw new Error('Expected image (BMP, JPEG, PNG, or GIF), but got unsupported ' +
        ^

Error: Expected image (BMP, JPEG, PNG, or GIF), but got unsupported image type
    at getImageType (/Users/xxx/app/server/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/dist/image.js:351:15)
    at Object.decodeImage (/Users/xxx/app/server/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/dist/image.js:196:21)
    at Socket.socket.on (/Users/xxx/app/server/app.js:37:29)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Socket.emitUntyped (/Users/xxx/app/server/node_modules/socket.io/dist/typed-events.js:69:22)
    at process.nextTick (/Users/xxx/app/server/node_modules/socket.io/dist/socket.js:428:39)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

Anybody has any clue as to why?

Answer (score 0):

The buffer data contains already the decoded image. To get the tensor out of it, here is simply what it takes on the server side:

```
tf.tensor(data).reshape([IMAGE_H, IMAGE_W, -1]); 
// IMAGE_H is the height of the image, here 180
// IMAGE_W is the width of the image, here 320
```

Comment: Thanks, @edkeveked, but how do I pass it to the `estimateSinglePose` then? Sorry, I don't know tensor very well.